# Whether a number is in a sorted matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a square n-by-n matrix of integers. The number of columns is equal to the number of rows.
Each column and row are sorted from the lowest to highest numbers. For example:

[image]

Another example:

[image]

I need an algorithm to find whether a given number is in the matrix, with a complexity of $n$ or lower.

Thanks people

Comment: I don't think that your first example is sorted.

Comment: Is some preprocessing allowed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is in fact easy. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-in-row-wise-and-column-wise-sorted-matrix/

You start from the top-right element.

- if smaller than the target, you can strike-out the row to the left;
- if larger than the target, you can strike-out the column to the bottom;
- repeat with the new top-right element, until you find the target.

E.g. looking for the value 65, not found:

[image]